# Airflow : Custom dates : Works fine with datetime but not with pendulum

Tags: airflow

**Requirement:** Create a custom date function to be used in operators, DAG, etc

Below is the DAG file

**DAG**

```py
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from alerts.custom_date import strt_of_wk_strt_mon_dt, NEXT_DS_NODASH

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2020, 7, 8),
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
}

dag = DAG(dag_id = 'test_date',
        schedule_interval='@once',
        default_args=default_args)


def test(**kwargs):

    first_date = kwargs.get('execution_date', None)
    strt_wk_dt = kwargs.get('strt_wk_dt')
    next_ds_nodash = kwargs.get('next_ds_nodash')
    s3_key = kwargs.get('s3_key')

    print(f'EXECUTION DATE:{first_date}')
    print(f'STRT_WK_DT:{strt_wk_dt}')
    print(f'NEXT_DS_NODASH:{next_ds_nodash}')
    print(f'S#_KEY:{s3_key}')

with dag:
    execution_date = '{{ execution_date }}'
    next_ds_nodash = NEXT_DS_NODASH
    strt_wk_dt = strt_of_wk_strt_mon_dt()

    t1 = PythonOperator(
        task_id='show_template',
        python_callable=test,
        op_kwargs={'execution_date': execution_date,
                   'next_ds_nodash': next_ds_nodash,
                   'strt_wk_dt': strt_wk_dt,
                   's3_key':f'snowflakes/FEEDS/{strt_wk_dt}/abc_{strt_wk_dt}.csv'},
        provide_context=True)
```

**With datetime package**
First I tried with using DateTime library and it worked fine as below screenshot

Below is the cstm_date.py

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

NEXT_DS_NODASH = '{{ (execution_date + macros.timedelta(days=1)).strftime("%m%d%Y") }}'

def strt_of_wk_strt_mon_dt():
    return (datetime.today().date() - timedelta(days=datetime.today().weekday())).strftime('%Y_%m_%d')
```

The output is printing as expected as below
[image]

Next, I tried with using pendulum library, the output is not printing the date value
** Pendulum package**

Below is the cstm_date.py

```py
import pendulum
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

NEXT_DS_NODASH = '{{ (execution_date + macros.timedelta(days=1)).strftime("%m%d%Y") }}'


def strt_of_wk_strt_mon_dt():
    today = pendulum.now()
    return today.start_of('week').format('YYYY_MM_DD')
```

The output is not printing the `STRT_WK_DT` value

[image]

**What am I missing?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the right conversion instruction for `datetime.strftime` but not using the string `datetime` conversion instruction in your new function that uses `pendulum`.

#### Yours

```py
def strt_of_wk_strt_mon_dt():
    today = pendulum.now()
    return today.start_of('week').format('YYYY_MM_DD')
```

#### Intended

```py
def strt_of_wk_strt_mon_dt():
    today = pendulum.now()
    return today.start_of('week').format('%Y_%m_%d')
```

Comment: I have defined a custom date function. How to get used as `{{strt_of_wk_strt_mon_dt}}` so that I can use in every operator or in every DAG

Comment: There's two ways this can be done. One, pass this in the dictionary you give to `params` arg in the Operator / Task Instance and call it in your templates through Jinja with `{{ params.strt_of_wk_strt_mon_dt }}`. Two, is a much bigger question, and one of it's own  I'm afraid.

Best of luck

Comment: Thanks, Mike Taylor, Should I open a new question to get answer for the second option?

Comment: I imported the function and tried as below `user_defined_macros={'strt_of_wk_strt_mon_dt': strt_of_wk_strt_mon_dt}` , it was not working .. Then i changed it to as `user_defined_macros={'strt_of_wk_strt_mon_dt': strt_of_wk_strt_mon_dt()}` which worked fine .. Issue here is Every DAG parse it will call the function which I dont want to